# How to count records by criteria in nodejs & mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following JSON object in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("585e34c50ab3cd228a8d6828"),
    "fullname" : "Name1",
    "status" : "INACTIVE",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-12-24T08:41:41.225Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-12-24T08:41:41.225Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("525e34c50ab3cd228a8d6828"),
    "fullname" : "Name2",
    "status" : "ACTIVE",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-12-24T08:41:41.225Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-12-24T08:41:41.225Z")
}
```

and the codes below return all count of all JSON objects.

```
db.collection(col).count(function (err, res) {
     if (err)
         throw err;
     db.close();
});
```

but i need to count only "ACTIVE" status results. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 db.collection(col).find({"status" : "ACTIVE"}).count(function (err, res) {
     if (err)
        throw err;
     console.log(res)
     db.close();
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

how about just:

```
db.collectionName.find({"status": "ACTIVE"}).count()
```

Im assuming your collection name is called "collectionName"

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      { $match: status: "ACTIVE" },
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

without `find()`

```
db.collection('anycollection')
    .count( { status : 'ACTIVE' }, (err, count) => {
        console.log(count);
    });
```

By the way , `count()` is deprecated now so more correct solution would be

```
db.collection('anycollection)
    .countDocuments( { status : 'ACTIVE' }, (err, count) => {
        console.log(count);
});
```